# Java MySQL JDBC Communication link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a server with a JDBC mysql connection, but every morning I got this error when I check the server:

> java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure:
>   java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.io.EOFException
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.io.EOFException
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1395)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1539)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2281)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1634)
>           at hu.craftbox.Server.CraftboxServerHandler.messageReceived(CraftboxServerHandler.java:158)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.messageReceived(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:184)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> ```
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1714)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2281)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1634)
>     at hu.craftbox.Server.CraftboxServerHandler.messageReceived(CraftboxServerHandler.java:158)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>     at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.messageReceived(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:184)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>     at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>     at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>     at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
> ```

What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: make sure both side use mysql connector correctly imported or not

Comment: There is not any problem with the connectors, because it connects to the mysql and works fine. The problem is that it throws the connection with this error during night.

Comment: Check [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,16257,33865#msg-33865), its maybe help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL drops unused connections after a while because it assumes that the other side forgot to close it.

What you need to do is to configure you MySQL correctly depends on your business,
Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html) how to configure your MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with an automatic ping function which prevents MySQL to drop connection because inactivity.

Comment: @TMS can u explain what is 'automatic ping function'